# iOS UIActionSheet for NSDataDetector and double modal view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I am having an issue with the detected numbers in iOS 7 and iPhone, when the user long tap the number detected by the OS, it prompts an UIActionSheet with the options: "Call", "Send Message", "Add to Contacts", "Copy" and "Cancel". The problem I am facing is, when the option "Send Message" or "Add to Contacts" is tapped, the OS creates an modal view on top of my current modal view, which leads to having the navigation bar of the second modal view not being displayed correctly.

With that in mind, I am not able to assert at which moment the user has tapped which button, because it is not me who created the UIActionSheet (iOS does itself), then I can not receive any kind of delegate methods. The only message sent to the UIViewController is:

```
      -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL 
              inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

Which tells me what kind of data was tapped once by the user (but not long tapped). I tried as well with the method call:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

Unfortunately, they are never invoked on iOS7, whereas iOS8 does. Which drives me to the conclusion that, so far, this issue is only iOS7 related, I am using an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2. When I tried the same case in iOS8, the second modal view renders correctly, being placed on top of my current view.

I hope someone has more info or other ideas.

Thanks!!

[image: iOS UIActionSheet for the phone]
[image: Wrong navigation bar, it lies on top of the normal "Add contacts" navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended up applying was to completely avoid the long press gesture on the title number that was generating the action sheet to appear. I did it checking on the gesture recognizer list for the UITextView that was inside the cell, then look up for one that was of the class `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, inside I would just disable the friend gesture. Snippet of code is:

RestrictedTextView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RestrictedTextView : UITextView

@end
```

RestrictedTextView.m

```
#import "RestrictedTextView.h"

NSString *const kFriendsStringInGesture = @"friends";

@implementation RestrictedTextView

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([[gestureRecognizer class] isEqual:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        longPress.enabled = YES;
        if ([longPress valueForKey:kFriendsStringInGesture] != nil)
        {
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *friendLongPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)[[longPress valueForKey:@"friends"] anyObject];
            friendLongPress.enabled = NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```